# Force Rails to re-render a view after a new Ajax GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Here's my fairly simple scenario: I have a basic MVC setup, and in my view, I have a drop-down list that it supposed to enable users to select different databases to connect to.  So, by default, the page loads and my controller establishes a connection to the default db, call it DB_Foo (which actually extends ActiveRecord::Base), and my view renders a table using the data from DB_Foo.  It looks something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @db_to_use = params[:db].nil? ? DB_Foo : params[:db]
    # imagine some code to establish_connection
    @table_data = @db_to_use.all
  end
end
```

Then, in my view, I can render the data by looping over `@table_data.to_a`.

Now, I go to select a different database, say DB_Bar from the drop-down, and I trigger a jQuery.get() call (shorthand for Ajax GET) to the same controller, passing in DB_Bar as a parameter.  I can verify that upon this new request getting routed to my controller, it sees the DB_Bar parameter I passed, and is able to establish the connection to DB_Bar.  I've verified that @table_data now contains the new data from DB_Bar, by the end of the `index` method.

What I want is basically for Rails to re-render the same view using the same controller, but with a different set of data from DB_Bar instead of DB_Foo.  But, nothing gets updated in my browser, which to me, means that no rendering of my view is happening (if it did, it would use the new data in @table_data and I would see it).

Am I horribly off-track with this design?  Must I use a jQuery callback on the .get() to modify the HTML elements manually?  Shouldn't Rails just render my page again with the new data?

Comment: A web app doesn't push data down to the browser.  It only responds to requests.  So your js code running on the browser needs to ask for the page again.

Comment: It did though, with the .get().  I'm responding to the new request, which is telling the server to switch from DB_Foo to DB_Bar (this I've verified by printing to the console on the server).  It's just not re-rendering the attached/default view.  I guess my question can be asked this way: if my route is setup to handle "get 'myroute/' => 'mycontroller#index'", then what is the difference between hitting "myroute" with a browser, versus firing a get() to the same URL from js?

Comment: What if you established a different action in the controller that you call via AJAX, and have that action pass your database parameter in a redirect to the index action?

Comment: Ok, I could see that working, but in that case, I guess my question is, why is that necessary?  I'm sure I'm doing something pretty stupid at this point... put it another way, I know that I can setup a real Ajax flow, where my .get() returns some data, and then I have a success callback that manually inserts my new data into the page's HTML.  I just wanted to take advantage of Rails's rendering if I could, as I thought this was a perfectly normal thing to ask my Rails app to do ("go render this page again with some different data instead, using the same action").

Comment: From what I understand, 'render' doesn't reload data from the action, but rather displays the page with the original data sent to the action.  That's why redirecting to index from a separate action works: it forces rails to reload the data for the index view.

Comment: > "Must I use a jQuery callback on the .get() to modify the HTML elements manually?" -- Yes.